# Error when executing a python requests post script

Tags: python

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong with the script below, but i keep getting this error when i try to execute the script. any idea what i'm doing wrong? thanks!

[image]

```
import requests

blxr_endpoint = "https://bxgw-nd-061-866-537.p2pify.com"
authorization = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

blxr_request_json = {
    "method": "blxr_tx",
    "params": {
        "transaction": signed_txn.rawTransaction.hex()[2:],
    }
}

result = requests.post(blxr_endpoint,json = blxr_request_json,auth = authorization)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less familiar with the `auth` param , but from [requests docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)  the auth param doesn't get string as an input.
It supposed to get a class that inherits from `requests.auth.AuthBase` like:
HTTPBasicAuth
HTTPDigestAuth
OAuth1

and other(you can also create one yourself.)
Another option is to insert the `Authorization` header of the http manually:

```
result  = requests.post(blxr_endpoint, headers={'Authorization': authorization})
```

Comment: do you think im doing this wrong? i'm trying to follow the documentation here: https://docs.bloxroute.com/apis/sending-transactions

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Bodeke56! It may be helpful for future community members if you would be able to provide a contrived code sample of the implementation details you are referencing. A brief summary of what the examples intent could also be helpful.

Comment: @Bobo If you are talking about the Python example in the documentation you supplied there is no use of the 'requests' package, but some property library called "bxcommon" and "bloxroute_cli".  

If you are trying to implement the HTTP request by yourself - I have update my answer to include a code example.